# FullCalendar Ember Support

Tags: ember.js, fullcalendar

Is there an Ember version of FullCalendar that uses the latest version of FullCalendar? I do not see Ember listed as a third party tool on there web site. https://fullcalendar.io/docs

I only see TypeScript, React, Vue and Angular listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to check for this is [ember observer](https://www.emberobserver.com/?query=fullcalendar).

There seems to be 3 addons for this. However 2 look very outdated.
The [last one](https://github.com/mariana-tek/ember-fullcalendar) however is pretty new.